# How to ignore new values in Observer during execution

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I have some Subject. And one Observer subscribed to it. How to omit all Observer invocations if it is already processing one?

```
var subject = new Subject();
var observer = {
        next: x => {
            //... some long processing is here
            console.log('Observer got a next value: ' + x)
        }
    };
subject.subscribe(observer);
subject.next(0);
subject.next(1);// <-- if 0 value is not processed in the observer then skip it
subject.next(2);// <-- if 0 value is not processed in the observer then skip it
```

I of cause can introduce some `flag`, set it in Observer before execution and clear it after. And apply filter operator, like this:

```
var subject = new Subject();
var flag = true;
var observer = {
    next: x => {
        flag = false;
        //... some long processing is here
        console.log('Observer got a next value: ' + x)
        flag = true;
        }
    };
subject.filter(() => flag).subscribe(observer);
subject.next(0);
subject.next(1);// <-- if previous value is not processed in the observer then skip it 
subject.next(2);// <-- if 0 value is not processed in the observer then skip it
```

But I believe that exists more elegant and efficient way to achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `exhaustMap` operator instead of trying roll your own backpressure. It is designed to ignore new events while waiting for the current one to complete.

```
const clicks = fromEvent(document, 'click');
const result = clicks.pipe(
  exhaustMap((ev) => interval(1000).pipe(take(5))),
);
result.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working. But one question, how to handle `error` and `complete` events of the inside Observable then?

Comment: Depends on where you want to handle them and what you want to do with them. If you are talking about per event handling, then you would handle the error with a `catchError`, `retry/When` operator right after the `take` in this example. You can also use `tap` if you need side-effecting behavior, or `materialize` if you actually want "complete" and "error" events to behave like normal events.